# counting number of occurances of a number in mysql -codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to find the number of occurrences of `open_id_fk` in this table. I am using the below code in my model.

```
 $this->db->select('open_id_fk, COUNT(open_id_fk) as total');
 $this->db->group_by('open_id_fk'); 
 $this->db->order_by('total', 'desc'); 
 $query = $this->db->get('voting_ip', 10);
 return $query;
```

[image]

> Expected Output:
>
> 116 - 2 occurances 118 - 1 occurances 119 - 1 occurances
>
> Acutual Output recieved:
>
> 116- 6 occurances 118- 3 occurances 119- 2 occurances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `COUNT(open_id_fk)` to `COUNT(*)` in your query

```
 $this->db->select('open_id_fk, COUNT(*) as total');
 $this->db->group_by('open_id_fk'); 
 $this->db->order_by('total', 'desc'); 
 $query = $this->db->get('voting_ip', 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
COUNT(*)
```

instead of

```
COUNT(open_id_fk)
```

will work